# BeautifulSoup Only Scraping Last Result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape runner names and number of tips from this page: https://www.horseracing.net/racecards/newmarket/13-05-21

It is only returning the last runner name in the final race. I've been over and over it but can't see what I have done wrong.

Can anyone see the issue?

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.horseracing.net/racecards/newmarket/13-05-21"

results = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

date = []
course = []
time = []
runner = []
tips = []

runner_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='row-cell-right')

for container in runner_div:

    runner_name = container.h5.a.text
    runner.append(runner_name)

    tips_no = container.find('span', class_='tip-text number-tip').text if container.find('span', class_='tip-text number-tip') else ''
    tips.append(tips_no)


print(runner_name, tips_no)
```

Comment: Have you tried to print `runner` and `tips` instead of `print(runner_name, tips_no)` ?

Comment: Merci bien Alexandre! Ca marche

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `print(runner, tips)` instead of `print(runner_name, tips_no)`:

Output:

```
print(runner, tips)
# ['Babindi', 'Turandot', 'Sharla', "Serena's Queen", 'Bellazada', 'Baby Alya', 'Adelita', 'Florence Street', 'Allerby', 'Puy Mary', 'Roman Mist', 'Lunar Shadow', 'Breakfastatiffanys', 'General Panic', 'Gidwa', 'Point Lynas', 'Three Dons', 'Wrought Iron', 'Desert Dreamer', 'Adatorio', 'Showmedemoney', 'The Charmer', 
# 'Bascinet', 'Dashing Rat', 'Appellation', 'Cambridgeshire', 'Danni California', 'Drifting Sands', 'Lunar Gold', 'Malathaat', 'Miss Calacatta', 'Sunrise Valley', 'Sweet Expectation', 'White Lady', 'Riknnah', 'Aaddeey', 'High Commissioner', 'Kaloor', 'Rodrigo Diaz', 'Mukha Magic', 'Gauntlet', 'Hawridge Flyer', 'Clovis Point', 'Franco Grasso', 'Kemari', 'Magical Land', 'Mobarhin', 'Movin Time', 'Night Of Dreams', 'Punta Arenas', 'Constanta', 'Cosmic George', 'Taravara', 'Basilicata', 'Top Brass', 'Without Revenge', 'Grand Scheme', 'Easy Equation', 'Mr Excellency', 'Colonel Faulkner', 'Urban War', 'Freak Out', 'Alabama Boy', 'Anghaam', 'Arqoob', 'Fiordland', 'Dickens', "Shuv H'Penny King"]
# ['5', '3', '1', '3', '1', '', '1', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '12', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '5', '', '1', '', '', '7', '', '', '1', '11', '1', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '1', '3', '2', '9', '', '', '', '', '5', '1', '4', '', '5', '', '1', '4', '2', '1', '3', '2', '1', '', '', '']
```